# Replace specific characters in string

Tags: shell, applescript

I have this AppleScript snippet that works fine replacing ` with ' :

```
set strng to "Output`s new form should not be these'\\''chars"
set modifiedString to replaceChars(strng, "`", "'")

on replaceChars(inputText, charsOut, charsIn)
    set text item delimiters to charsOut
    set textList to text items of inputText
    set modifiedList to {}
    repeat with textItem in textList
        set end of modifiedList to textItem as text
    end repeat
    set text item delimiters to charsIn
    set resultText to modifiedList as text
    set text item delimiters to ""
    return resultText
end replaceChars
```

I'd like to expand this so that it also searches for '\\'' sequence and replaces with ' .
Kind of like:

```
set modifiedString to replaceChars(strng, {"`", "'\\''"}, "'")
```

How do I filter for this additional string?

Note, I'm open to doing this via shell command as well but so far only this approach has worked for me with the "`" character.

Comment: You need to keep in mind that the backslash is the escape character, so in that `strng` variable there is actually only one backslash since it is being escaped.

Comment: Unrelated but the repeat loop is redundant. Write `set resultText to textList as text` and delete the repeat loop and the `modifiedList` initialization.

Answer (score 0):

```
set modifiedString to replaceChars(strng, {"`", "'\\''"}, "'")
```

...is what worked for me after all.
Thanks for input